# How to center align a value with a comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

All the values is center align like the numbers but the values with with the comma left align how can I initially center align those values with a comma.

[image]

```js
contentHtml += "<td rowspan1=\"" 
  +   1 
  + "\" class=\"" 
  + (rowspan !== "" && rowspan > 1 ? "groups" : "") 
  + " " 
  + (!isNaN(value) || (!isNaN(value.toString().substr(1, value.length)) || value == "N/A" || value.length < 7 && value.toString().substr(value.length - 1) == '%' && value.length == ',') ? "text-center" : "text-left") 
  + "\">"
  + value 
  + (!isNaN(value) ? preFix : "") + color + (!isNaN(value) ? postFix : "") + "</td>"
```

Comment: `td {text-align: middle}` doesn't work anymore ?

Comment: `value.length == ','` O.o

Comment: That value.lenght == ',' does not work Im looking for some code similar that will center align the comma values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking to use is `indexOf()`. Like so:

```
value.toString().indexOf(',')
```

This will return a integer. If `,` is in the string, it will return the index value from 0 to some other number. It will return -1 if the character does not exist in the string.

Example:

```
var value = "1,965";
var index = value.indexOf(",");
console.log(index);
```

This would result in `index` being 1.

In your script this may look like:

```
+ (!isNaN(value) || (!isNaN(value.toString().substr(1, value.length)) || value == "N/A" || value.length < 7 && value.toString().substr(value.length - 1) == '%' || value.toString().indexOf(',') > 0) ? "text-center" : "text-left")
```

I suspect you could drop the whole bit. You want `567` or `1,964` to appear centered, if you remove that condition from test, it would be centered for either.

I would test both ways and see.